# WebDAV for Django Application

Tags: python, django, webdav

Wanted features:

- WebDAV server
- Use should be able to edit a microsoft excel spreadsheet via this WebDAV server
- User Authentication via Django
- open source licence. Not GPL or AGPL
- Include Blobs from different sources (files system, s3, ...)

Not wanted:

- Storing static files in WebDAV (https://github.com/marazmiki/django-webdav-storage)